# my_meta not saving in my current hosting

Tags: php

***from the legendado plrn1 it does not saveif 
I remove it, there it is saved***

```
<!-- S_POST BOX -->
<div class="modal fade S_POST" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md box_ove_top" style="width: 60%;">
        <div class="modal-content bg_fall_spost">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php 
                    if(!empty($meta['s_post'])) {
                        $s_post = $meta['s_post'];
                        for ($i=1; $i<=$s_post; $i++){
                            print   '<div class="mb_10">';
                            print       '<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#'.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="'.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'">T'.$i.'</a>';
                            print       '<span class="mlr_5px dis_in"><input type="checkbox" class="chec_b" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_d]" value="ok"'; if(isset($meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_d'])){if($meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_d'] == 'ok'){print 'checked';}} print '>Dublado</span>';;

                            print       '<span class="mlr_5px dis_in"><input type="checkbox" class="chec_b" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_l]" value="ok"'; if(isset($meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_l'])){if($meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_l'] == 'ok'){print 'checked';}} print '>Legendado</span>';

                            print       '<div class="collapse" id="'.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'">';
                            print           '<div class="mb_10">T'.$i.': <input type="number" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.']" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i].'"/></div>';
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i];
                                            $s_pline = $meta[$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i];

                                            if(!empty($s_pline)) {

                                                for ($e=1; $e<=$s_pline; $e++){

                                                    $s_audid = $meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_d'];
                                                    $s_audil = $meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_l'];

                                                    $s_audid2 = $meta[$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i.'_d2'];
                                                    $s_audil2 = $meta[$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i.'_l2'];

                                                    $s_audid3 = $meta[$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i.'_d3'];
                                                    $s_audil3 = $meta[$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i.'_l3'];

                                                    $s_audid4 = $meta[$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i.'_d4'];
                                                    $s_audil4 = $meta[$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i.'_l4'];

                                                    $s_audid5 = $meta[$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i.'_d5'];
                                                    $s_audil5 = $meta[$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i.'_l5'];

                                                    $s_audid01 = $meta[$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i.'_d01'];
                                                    $s_audil01 = $meta[$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i.'_l01'];

                                                    $s_audid02 = $meta[$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i.'_d02'];
                                                    $s_audil02 = $meta[$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i.'_l02'];

                                                    $s_audid03 = $meta[$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i.'_d03'];
                                                    $s_audil03 = $meta[$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i.'_l03'];

                                                    print '<div class="mb_10">';
                                                    if(isset($s_audid) && $s_audid == 'ok') {

                                                        print '<div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;"><label>Dublado</label></div>';

                                                        print '<div>EP'.$e.' <b>Dublado</b>: <input style="width: 45%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d]" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d'].'" placeholder="Link player_1"/>

                                                        <input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d01]" value="'.$meta[$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d01'].'" placeholder="Nome player"></div>';

                                                        print '<div>EP'.$e.' <b>Dublado</b>: <input style="width: 45%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d2]" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d2'].'" placeholder="Link player_2"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d02]" value="'.$meta[$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d02'].'" placeholder="Nome player"></div>';

                                                        print '<div>EP'.$e.' <b>Dublado</b>: <input style="width: 45%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d3]" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d3'].'" placeholder="Link player_3"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d03]" value="'.$meta[$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d03'].'" placeholder="Nome player"></div>';

                                                        print '<div><b>Capa e Nome</b>: <input style="width: 35%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d4]" value="'.$meta[$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d4'].'" placeholder="Capa player"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 30%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d5]" value="'.$meta[$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'d5'].'" placeholder="Nome do epsódio"/></div>';
                                                    }

                                                    if(isset($s_audil) && $s_audil == 'ok') {
                                                        print '<div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;"><label>Legendado</label></div>';

                                                        print '<div>EP'.$e.' <b>Leg</b>: <input style="width: 45%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l]" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l'].'" placeholder="Link player_1"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l01]" value="'.$meta[$meta['plrn1'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l01'].'" placeholder="Nome player"></div>';

                                                        print '<div>EP'.$e.' <b>Leg</b>: <input style="width: 45%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l2]" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l2'].'" placeholder="Link player_2"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l02]" value="'.$meta[$meta['plrn2'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l02'].'" placeholder="Nome player"></div>';

                                                        print '<div>EP'.$e.' <b>Leg</b>: <input style="width: 45%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l3]" value="'.$meta[$meta['cts_key3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l3'].'" placeholder="Link player_3"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l03]" value="'.$meta[$meta['plrn3'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l03'].'" placeholder="Nome player"></div>';

                                                        print '<div><b>Capa e Nome</b>: <input style="width: 35%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l4]" value="'.$meta[$meta['capasr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l4'].'" placeholder="Capa player"/>
                                                        <input style="width: 30%;" type="text" class="mx_plans" name="_my_meta['.$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l5]" value="'.$meta[$meta['nomesr'].'_'.$i.'_'.$e.'l5'].'" placeholder="Nome do epsódio"/></div>';
                                                    }
                                                    print '</div>';
                                                }
                                            }
                            print       '</div>';
                            print   '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: The code in your question is incomplete, the save code is missing, as is the surrounding context for the code block, is it in a file on its own? Or a function? There are also indenting issues, I fixed the formatting in the question too so it was visible. Where does `$meta` come from?

Comment: is in funcition
I do not know if it is my hosting, therefore I tested thema with the same code in another hosting and the goal is saving when you update the post